# How can i write multiple images URLs in one list array of query . Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to get a list of URLs in Firebase storage. I want to add this to my Firestore user's data. Or I don't know how can I save these in user data for showing posts user profile page in app.
For example:

1. Create a post like instagram,
2. I type some text description,
3. choose 3 images in gallery.

I want to save the URLs for these images in one document, instead of into three separate documents as my code currentlly does.

My code is:

```dart
   Future uploadInfo() async {
    for (var img in _image) {
      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('images/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
      await ref.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          posts
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .collection('userPosts')
              .add(
            {
              'imgUrl': value,
            },
          );
        });
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: This code working normally, but (for in) save each images url in separate documents. İ want to get list of Url to save each user data , which is logged in with uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list that holds the list of image urls and you can just add the list to the collection.
See below:

```dart
     Future uploadInfo() async {
        List<String> imageUrlList = []; 
        for (var img in _image) {
          ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('images/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
          await ref.putFile(img);
          final String downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
          imageUrlList.add(downloadUrl); 
        }
        posts.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).collection('userPosts')
          .add(
              {
                'imageUrlList': imageUrlList,
              },
          );
        
     }
```

Check out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make imageUrlList = list of imageURLs;
2. convert to string imageUrlList.toString() and then save the data into one document.
3. When using this document just use jsonDecode(documentListOfUrlString) and you will get the list of images.